# Django keeps giving error 'ArticleView' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: django

I already solved the problem by adding serializer_classes but it keeps giving me the same error. It did the same to me before even if i solved it . Did i miss something here?

**Views.py**

```
class ArticleView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer = ArticleCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            serializer_context = {
            'request': request
            }
            serializer_data = request.data.get('article',{})
            serializer = self.get_serializer_class(data=serializer_data, context=serializer_context, )
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'success': True})
            else:
                return Response({'success': False})
        except:
            return Response({'success': False})
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ArticleCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    caption = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author','caption')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author = self.context['request'].user.profile
        article = Article.objects.create(author=author,**validated_data)
        return article
```

Does anyone knows why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `serializer = ArticleCreateSerializer` with `serializer_class = ArticleCreateSerializer`.

Follow DRF guide on [Generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/).